# Teleporting certain people

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating a server were there is a jail. I need to have certain people (cops) be able to shoot them or something like that and be teleported to the jail. I just don't know how to make this work. should I use a command block or something else???

Comment: What part are you struggling with on how to put it together?

Comment: I'm going to try this over and over, ill tell you were i get stuck.

Comment: this might complicate things more but i am playing on the original mine craft. what do you mean bye redstone block, it doesn't power anything.

Comment: okay @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms i am now running into problems with the coding.with the third command block it says "can't teleport blocks out of world, this is what i have for that code"/setblock 446~ 1~ 1366~ redstone_block 0 destroy. i then have a block of redstone, then the 2nd command block. /testfor @e [type=snowball]. then the redstone compositor which is pointed away from the 2nd command block. then on to the redstone repeater which is set back 2 notches then the last command block. the last code is /execute @e[type=snowball] /tp @p 414 1 -1350. if you see what is wrong please tell me

Comment: The numbers you put next to the ~ mark should be numbers __relative__ to the __command block__ __not__ coordinates in the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method I came up with while pondering your question, be warned though, I haven't had a chance to test it out, but I think it might work. Here are the commands and command block setup:

```
1: /testfor @e[type=snowball]
2: /execute @e[type=snowball] /tp @p <x> <y> <z>
3: /setblock ~ ~ ~ redstone_block 0 destroy
```

Remember to put numbers next to the ~ symbols to tell the command where to place the redstone block relative to the command block so it's constantly running the command in the next command block. Now here's the setup, please note that being able to to what I am telling you to do does require basic command and redstone knowledge:

```
1 = command block #1
2 = command block #2
3 = command block #3
[] = redstone comparator
{} = redstone repeater with a 2 tick delay
# = redstone block

3#1[]{}2
```

Also, you might want to run this command as to not lag your server:

```
/gamerule doTileDrops false
```

I also forgot to mention, you must be playing in **snapshot 14w21a** or later.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, i seem to be stuck on how to put it together. i know basic redstone knowledge but i seem to have trouble with understanding how they are supposed to stay active.

Comment: @pace Could you be specific about what part of it you are struggling with?

Comment: I seem to question how it is working, whenever i do as you say it doesn't work. here is how i am doing it, please tell me if i am doing anything wrong-

Comment: 1: /testfor @e[type=snowball]
2: /execute @e[type=snowball] /tp @p 418 4 -1325
3: /setblock ~ ~ ~ redstone_block 0 destroy

Comment: @pace Are you playing in the latest snapshot? This does require you to play in the latest snapshot.

Comment: Remember to put a number after every __~__ to place a redstone block relative to the command block to activate the next command block constantly.

Comment: yes i am playing in latest, but what do you keen bye numbers relative to the command block?

Comment: There are a few flaws with this system:

@p will most likely target the player who threw the snowball.

If you avoid that with @p[score_cop=0], then it will teleport people every time it is thrown regardless of whether they were hit; even from hundreds of blocks away, and all a cop has to do is throw a bunch up in the air and everyone will be in jail.

It wouldn't work at all when a cop throws multiple snowballs or two police are throwing snowballs at the same time.

Also, if the snowball actually hits someone, it wouldn't TP them as the entity no longer exists to /execute the command.

Comment: @colorfusion That is why there is a two tick delay, it should pause for enough time to make sure that the person throwing the snowball doesn't get hit.

Comment: @pace What I mean by numbers relative to the command block is, lets say I wanted to place the redstone block directly above the command block, I would type `/setblock ~ ~1 ~ redstone_block 0 destroy`. I hope this helps explain what I mean by, "relative to the command block."

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms thank you so much, it is starting to work for me. I know that I have asked a lot of you but could you help me with two more things that I know can be done. I am trying to make a currency with golden nuggets but I need help with the coding of it. i also need help with a bank I'm making. I would like for a chest to be able to spawn a certain number of golden nuggets. after they are taken i want those nuggets to go away so they can't take anymore. could anyone help me?

Comment: @pace Maybe ask a new question?